# Editing the contents of a DB with a dynamic form/webpage

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms, web-applications

I am looking for advice on what tools and resources to use and read up on to solve my problem.

The project is a database driven website built with php, html, css, sql and some javascript.

In my project, I want to allow the user to go back to data previously entered into the multi-table database and give them the option of either deleting or editing that data.

Rather than updating the DB after each change, I would like the user to be able to make all the changes on the client side, for the webpage to dynamically change to show these changes then when the save button is pressed the PHP will write the appropriate queries and amend the DB.

If this was a simple structure, I know I could do this with a simple text form. Unfortunately, it's a little more complicated than that. The DB is for logging hiking trips, and I want to give the user an option to "remove a friend" from the trip. This would involve the people listed on the trip having a delete button next to their name, when the user clicks that delete button I would like to see the name removed from the webpage and changes are only made to the DB once the save button is pushed.

I'm just at the start of this part of my project and don't have any code yet, but interested in reading and learning about the correct things first in order to get me started.

I am self-taught and have some basic knowledge of php, html, css, sql and I've been fairly successful in implementing other peoples javascript code within my project.

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I hope I have been clear in describing my issue and if you have any questions then please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

With the technologies that you are using, the way that I would do this would be to create an object model for change tracking on your objects in your client javascript.

You would also need an object model for the entities themselves, in the clientside javascript. This is because, if you are not updating the entities on the server, reloading them from there would override the changes that the user already made.

**Step 1** would be to have all the entities that the user is getting displayed/have available for changing should be "cached" client side in javascript objects, and rendered to the page from there.

**Step 2** would them be to introduce the object model that will track the changes. An object could look like this:

```
{
  "changeType": "remove-friend-from-trip",
  "friendId": 12,
  "tripId": 27
}
```

And whenever the user would make a change, you would push that change as a javascript object into a local collection where you maintain all the changes. You would also update the local javascript object that is being displayed.

**Step 3** would be to implement the logic of the "save" function for a page. It should go through the changes in the local collection of tracked changes, and translate those to the appropriate posts to the webserver.

And issue here might be to handle the local objects between full page reloads, it would have to be cookie based I think - in order to survive. Unless the application is already an SPA.

There is also some frameworks available for things like this I think - [here's one that I found](https://github.com/benjamine/tent) that appers to do something like what you want. However, the time it would take to adopt such a framework, might be greater than the time to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Lots to look into here and exactly what I was needing to get me started.